# Magento 2: Batch for CLI-commands

Tags: magento2, cli

I am often using the following commands one after another:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to create a batch-command (like in old MS-DOS-systems) to run the commands with one command. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just separate the commands by semi-colon and run them on CLI, as simple as that. The set of commands get executed one by one.

```
$php bin/magento setup:upgrade;php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
```

Comment: If you are looking for some other way to do it, just let me know

Comment: This is really cool, many thanks: Works like a charm!